# Linking Many to Many associations in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a website for asking questions and getting answers. When a question is asked, I want to be able to tag the new question with multiple topics. Using a multiselect, I've sent back an array of topic_ids to the controller. I've been following Cake's documentation but I've been getting lots of errors.

Is this the proper way to link associated entities with a many to many relationship? I can provide more information or code if it's needed.

```
$question = $this->Questions->newEntity();

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $topics = array_map(
        function($id) {
            $topic = $this->Questions->Topics->get($id);
            $topic->_joinData = $this->Questions->TopicsQuestions->newEntity();
            // user_id is metadata in the topics_questions table
            $topic->_joinData->user_id = $this->Auth->User()->id;

            return $topic;
        },
        // this is passed back as an array of topic_id
        $this->request->data['topics'];
    );

    $this->Questions->Topics->link($question, $topics);

    $question = $this->Questions->patchEntity($question, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Topics']]);

    if ($this->Questions->save($question)) {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $question->id]);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The question could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Whenever receiving errors, please add them into your question, including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!. Hint: what do the API docs of the `BelongsToMany::link()` method say about what the method does, and what kind of data it expects to be fed with?

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly new to cake. I know how to use the debug kit but I'm not sure how to get the stack trace in a readable form that I can copy and paste to here. With this code I get "500 Error RuntimeException"

"Both the source entity and each of the target entities are assumed to be already persisted" does this mean I need to make the call to link after I save the question?

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thanks a ton for your help and leading me to the solution instead of giving it to me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CakePHP API Docs:

> Both the source entity and each of the target entities are assumed to
>   be already persisted, if they are marked as new or their status is
>   unknown then an exception will be thrown.

So the call to link needed to be made after the question was saved.

Comment: Since the topics already exist in the database, I think you can make this even easier, by using the `_ids` method. See [Converting BelongsToMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data). That won't get you the user id in the join table, but you could use the [Footprint plugin](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint) to handle that automatically for you.